# I want to show default table model total (sum) data in all cell of Total Column

Tags: java, defaulttablemodel

Show calculated data in all cell of the column total.

[image: 0 is showing in all cell of total]

I don't know how to do this, when calculated it will show in all cell of the column of total.

```
final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Opening", "Purchase", "Total", "Consumption"}, 10) {
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        Object value = null;
        switch (col) {
            case 2:
                double opening = getAmountForRow(row);
                double purchase = getCostForRow(row);
                double cons=getconsForRow(row);
                value = opening + purchase-cons;
                break;
            default:
                value = super.getValueAt(row, col);
        }
        return value;
    }

    protected double getAmountForRow(int row) {
        return getNumberForRow(row, 0);
    }

    protected double getCostForRow(int row) {
        return getNumberForRow(row, 1);
    }

    protected double getconsForRow(int row) {
        return getNumberForRow(row, 3);
    }

    protected double getNumberForRow(int row, int col) {
        double number = 0;
        Object value = getValueAt(row, col);
        if (value != null && value instanceof Number) {
            number = ((Number) value).doubleValue();
        }
        return number;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
        if (column != 2) {
            if (aValue instanceof Number) {
                super.setValueAt(aValue, row, column);
                if (column == 0 || column == 1 || column==3) {
                    fireTableCellUpdated(row, 2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return Double.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return column != 2;
    }
};

final JTable table = new JTable(model);
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    // @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
            if (table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint()) < 0) {
                StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer();
                model.addRow(new Vector());
            }
        }
    }
});
model.addRow(new Vector());

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chemical");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setIconImage(null);
frame.setSize(700,500);
// frame.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
table.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Your code works for me. Could you clarify what you really expect and what you get?

Comment: Sir, i want the samenumber  in all cell of total column num when add the opening + purchase like zero in total column

Comment: want to save the data automatically when put data in cells and remain after again open the program

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you exactly try to display. The same number in column total for all rows? Even if there are differnet values in the other columns? Regarding the saving: Add a CellEditorListener that triggers the saving of the data. On starting you can read the data and prepopulate the model.

Comment: can you help me in this? celleditorlistener i want to save and remain the all data on cell after closing

Comment: where to add the celleditorlistener for saving data

Comment: Sorry, I was a little bit confused, I didn't mean CellEditorListener but TableModellListener. Have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange) as I definitely won't do your work for you. ;-)